# Android - Adding layout at runtime to main layout

Tags: android, dynamic, android-layout, runtime, addition

I am trying to add a tableLayout at runtime to the existing LinearLayout in main.xml.
I have added a editText(R.id.editText1) in the main.xml. Here's my code. Its not working. I get a runtime error (The application has stopped unexpectedly).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    TableLayout tblLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tblLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(8,5));
    tblLayout.setPadding(1,1,1,1);

    for(int r=0; r<ROW_COUNT; ++r)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        for(int c=0; c<COL_COUNT; ++c)
        {
            int index = r * COL_COUNT + c;
            buttonList.add(new Button(this));
            buttonList.get(index).setText(buttonNames[index]);
            tr.addView(buttonList.get(index), 60, 30);
        }
        tblLayout.addView(tr);
    }

    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main);
    mainLayout.addView(tblLayout);        

    setContentView(mainLayout);
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Paste your logcat. It could be any number of reasons... For example, buttonList might be null (did you instantiate it?)

Comment: As per the logcat, the error seems to be happening in this line CalculatorActivity.java:46 which is

mainLayout.addView(tblLayout);

I have instantiated buttonList.

Answer (score 0):

Before your loop add :

```
Arraylist<TableRow> tr = new ArrayList<TableRow>;
```

In the loop instead of :

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
```

Put :

```
tr.add(new TableRow(this));
```

And finally replace your `tr` by `tr.get(r)`. Something like these modifications should help you because, you erase your tr at each turn of your loop with your :

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Happy Go Lucky just do one thing write `setContentView(R.layout.your Main Layout);` beofre `text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);`
means at top of the `onCreate()` method because we cant define any `view` before `setContentView.`

without any `setContentView` you cant find any view like as `findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

Answer (score 0):

Below line will be the first one after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
 setContentView(mainLayout);
```

then only `findViewByid` works