# Still Can't Add Button to Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I just started android and I tried below questions to get this answer before posting it here:

[Android - Adding layout at runtime to main layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240939/android-adding-layout-at-runtime-to-main-layout)

[Add button to a layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907609/add-button-to-a-layout-programmatically)

[Dynamically adding a child to LinearLayout with getting each child's position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661745/dynamically-adding-a-child-to-linearlayout-with-getting-each-childs-position)

And I am still not able to add a button to linear layout :(

Below is the code for activity, please let me know where I am wrong:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_main, null);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(123);
        btn.setText("Welcome to WI FI World");
        layout.addView(btn);
    }
```

And xml looks like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to add your linear layout to the page. Im pretty sure those arent the same linear layouts. and so you are adding a button to one that isnt shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the Id for LinearLayout in XML and in jave code use that id of LinearLayout from XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear" >

</LinearLayout>
```

In onCreate():

```
LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);

 //Select widgets
 linear.addView()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning an id to your layout then add the button to the layout.

Im pretty sure those 2 layouts are not the same, so you are infact adding a button to a layout that is never displayed.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnr_main);

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(123);
    btn.setText("Welcome to WI FI World");
    layout.addView(btn);
}
```

With Layout assigned an id

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/lnr_main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give an id to your linearLayout.

Then in your code

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.given_id);
```

Keep the rest the same, should work.